# How do I restrict the stacktrace display on logs?

Tags: logback, slf4j, slf4j-api

I'm using logback 1.1.3 over slf4j-api 1.7.7.

I'm reading the following documentation [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html).

The code (which I can't modify) that I'm trying to restrict the logging logs and throws exceptions in the following way.

```
try {.. }
catch( Exception e ) {
  log.error( "Houston we have a problem", e );
  throw new TestException( "Houston we have a problem", e );
}
```

The log format I'm using is the following.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And I want some loggers to restrict the display of their stacktrace to just 2 lines so I thought I could simply modify that to the following format as stipulated in the documentation.

```
<appender name="STDOUT_COMPACT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %ex{2} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I was expecting to get something like the following.

```
mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
```

But instead, I was getting the following.

```
mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire1(TestThrower.java:12)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire2(TestThrower.java:44)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire3(TestThrower.java:122)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire4(TestThrower.java:322)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire5(TestThrower.java:72)
  ..
```

The log was simply repeated instead of being truncated to just 2 lines. What am I doing wrong? How exactly do I use the `ex{n}` format appropriately? I don't prefer to write my custom logger for this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to include %nopex in your pattern.  Otherwise Logback will tack on the stacktrace even though you've already printed the stacktrace.  Your pattern should look like this:

```
%ex{2} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%nopex%n
```

It's more common to include the exceptions on the end like this:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg %ex{2}%nopex%n
```

Comment: This contradicts the documentation in http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex which states that the stacktrace is only appended if no `%ex` token at all is present. Yes, I also tried it out.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I've looked at that link Michael, and it doesn't specify that you need %ex:

"If you do not specify %throwable or another throwable-related conversion word in the conversion pattern, PatternLayout will automatically add it as the last conversion word, on account of the importance of stack trace information. The $nopex conversion word can be substituted for %throwable, if you do not wish stack trace information to be displayed. See also the %nopex conversion word."

Comment: @MichaelPiefel It states that if you don't specify %throwable or the like, it will automatically add it as the last conversion word. But the $nopex conversion word can be substituted for that if **you do not wish stack information to be display** .. May I ask where the contradiction is?

Comment: @Raid: The pattern in _this answer_ contains `%ex`.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I know. He's putting it in a specific place instead of the end where it automatically appends. So he's choosing his placement where he wants the exception trace to be. Make sense? :)